# Задача об оптимальном распределении предметов в массивы разной длины

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

Вот суть задачи:

Есть коробки с определенной вместимостью (6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 25), есть яблоки, которые нужно оптимально разложить по коробкам, то есть чтоб коробки были максимально заполнены и кол-во коробок было минимальным. Нужно узнать сколько и каких коробок понадобится.

Пытался копать в сторону линейного программирования и жадных алгоритмов, но в голову так и не пришло решение.
Тут что ли нужно как-то вместе использовать ДП и жадные алгоритмы. Еще и не ясно, какое условие приоритетнее: заполненность коробок или их минимальное кол-во.

В общем, буду рад любой помощи, а особенно за пример кода.

Comment: *чтоб коробки были максимально заполнены и кол-во коробок было минимальным.* Критерий должен быть **ОДИН**. Выберите что-то одно, формируйте математическое выражение для минимизации, или ещё что...

Comment: Реализуйте оба алгоритма в зависимости от выбора критерия пользователем - они не настолько сложные

Comment: Если заполнять коробки от большей к меньшей, то количество коробок будет минимальным и без дополнительной оптимизации.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к ответу Harry. Если вы хотите максимизировать заполненность каждой коробки, то это задача о банкомате. Она решается за O(n*k), где n - это количество яблок, а k количество видов коробок.

https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=815